# regex for route restricting to numbers

Tags: angularjs, regex, ngroute

I currently have regex `/:id[0-9]+` for restricting routes containing numbers. It works only when the number is at least 2 digits long. How do I make it to take single digit numbers also

Thanks in advance
ex:

```
.when('/:id[0-9]+', { 
     templateUrl: 'app/issue/view/view.html',
     controller: 'viewIssueCtrl',
     reloadOnSearch: true,
    ....
    ...
  )
```

Comment: Actually I would think the regex `[0-9]+` would match _one_ or more digits, including two.  How did you ascertain that it doesn't match single digits?

Comment: Because it was redirecting to home page when I entered single digits, works fine only when I put /01, when i put /1, it goes back to .home.

Please note that I have other routes /home, /lastupdated, /configure as well, Do you think these routes may be interfering  ?

Comment: Hmm...I don't know ngroute, but perhaps something else is acting on the single digit use case?

Comment: All of my other routes are named, this is the only route i need to take variations

Comment: The regex is valid for your use case. If possible, I would comment out all other routes except this one and see the outcome

Comment: really strange, I commented out all other routes, still see same issue

Answer (score 0):

The default router for AngularJS does not support regular expressions in routes.

Should you be using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which supports regular expressions for routes then your route syntax is incorrect and should be changed to:-

```
.when('/{id:[0-9]+}', { 
     templateUrl: 'app/issue/view/view.html',
     controller: 'viewIssueCtrl',
     reloadOnSearch: true,
    ....
    ...
  )
```

Comment: You won't be able to use regex with ngRoute

Comment: is this /:id[0-9]+ not a regex?

Comment: It is but without additional modules you can not use it in your route. If you do it won't be processed as a regular expression